# SQL Column width from bytes to characters

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to calculate the maximum number of characters allowed in an SQL field.

For example, I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bla (
  TEST TEXT,
  SHORTER TEXT(30),
  NUMBER INT,
  SHNUMBER INT(30)
)
```

Using the PHP function mysqli_fetch_fields, like this:

```
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($res);
foreach($finfo as $value) {
    printf("Name:     %s\n", $value->name);
    printf("max. Len: %d\n", $value->length);
    printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $value->type);       
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Name: TEST  max.Len: 65535  Type: 252 
Name: SHORTER  max.Len: 255  Type: 252 
Name: NUMBER  max.Len: 11  Type: 3 
Name: SHNUMBER  max.Len: 30  Type: 3
```

My question is: how can I convert this max lenght (represented as number of bytes) back to a number of decimals, characters, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `show columns` command to retreive the information about the columns in your table. See the [documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html).